# Can't uninstall Reporting Services on SQL 2005 (SBS 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, windows-sbs-2008, ssrs

I am running SBS 2008 and have just installed SQL 2008 alongside SQL 2005. My understanding is that the default instance created in SQL 2005 is not needed and only the SBSMONITORING instance is needed. I have removed the default instance (as i want to create a new default instance in SQL 2008) and everything has worked but the reporting services remains installed and i can't get rid of it. No error messages are generated during the uninstall process so i have no idea what is going on.

Any thoughts?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of SBS (sorry!) however I don't believe that you can have SSRS 2005 installed on a box which has SQL Server 2008.  Therefore I wouldn't worry about it and just go ahead and install 2008, it will upgrade SSRS if necessary.